# Why my Git Bash is crashing when opening it and not starting?

Tags: bash, git, visual-studio, github, terminal

Directory C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc does not exist; exiting

If directory name is garbage you need to update your msys package
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Git Bash and update MSYS package.

Also check your system path to make sure MSYS package is set correctly in your system environment variables.
`Control Panel > System and Security > System > Advanced system settings > Advanced tab > Environment Variables`

Check etc directory if missing. Usually recreated in Git Bash installation directory `C:\Program Files\Git\etc`

Comment: Now I have error for installing MSYS2
installer error
error during installation process (com.msys2.root.base):
Execution failed (Unexpected exit code: 1): "C:\msys64\usr\bin\bash.exe --login -c exit"

Comment: This is different issue, you could try running MSYS2 as admin, see if you have all dependencies such as vcc runtime etc